# Keep code always formatted properly?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to make visual studio keep the code always formatted properly? I use the format document and selection but it wastes time. Any solutions? Third party tools welcome too.

Answer (score 3):

I use [CodeMaid](https://bitbucket.org/s_cadwallader/codemaid/wiki/Home) that formats the document (and performs some other, configurable stuff such as removing extra blank lines and similar) automatically on save. Available for 2005/2008/2010 (I only used it in VS2010).

Answer (score 2):

See [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) and [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) and also [Universal Indent GUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+A followed by Ctrl+K, D

Which are the standard keys (C# profile) for Select All, Format Document.  Find it doesn't take much time at all.

Comment: BTW The select all is not needed for a format document; it is required if you are using format selection (`Ctrl+K+F`, I believe, for your keyboard layout).

Comment: Darn.  I've been waisting a key press all these years. :D

Comment: Not necessarily. "Format Document" is not available in C++. See [this suggestion](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/474154/add-the-format-document-command-to-c-projects), and [this older suggestion](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/101894/add-format-document-to-c) on Microsoft Connect.